# Scraping Authors based on tags from Google Scholar

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, google-scholar

I am working on a project where I hope to scrape data from Google Scholar. I want to scrape all authors tagged in a category (eg. [Anaphylaxis](https://scholar.google.co.uk/citations?view_op=search_authors&hl=en&mauthors=label:anaphylaxishttps://scholar.google.co.uk/citations?view_op=search_authors&hl=en&mauthors=label:anaphylaxis)) and store their number of citations, h-index and i-10 index in a CSV file. However, I am unsure how to do this given that Google Scholar has no API. I understand I can use a scraper like beautiful soup but am unsure how to scrape the data without being blocked.

So, my question is how can I use bs4 to store all authors tagged as Anaphylaxis and each author's citations, h-index and i-10 index in a csv file.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: @Peaceful Have updated to clarify

Comment: Sounds quite interesting! I don't have an answer, especially about being blocked. However, perhaps you haven't seen https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scholarly/0.2.2? Code could be patterned on those results.

Comment: @BillBell The question doesn't say clearly whether it is about getting blocked or about extracting particular things. Moreover he has not mentioned anything about what they tried so far.

Comment: @Peaceful: All true to some extent, my friend, but I don't mind and, what's more, now that you've mentioned those factors, there's no need for me to do so. :) I actually think the nature of the question can be  gleaned if read carefully enough. If you try to use scholars to obtain a series of h-index values for all of the people in 'Anaphylaxis', isn't there a good chance you'll be blocked?

Comment: @BillBell : Is that the question? Frankly speaking, if you keep 1 sec pause between every page hit, nobody would block you.

Comment: @Peaceful: To be honest, I didn't know. Then that's part of an answer.

Answer (score 0):

All the scraper is doing is parsing some HTML pages.  Upon a search, the authors are in the div with class = "gs_a"  If you use Beautiful Soup and look for this class you will be able to find all of the authors.  You can go page by page by updating the url.

https://scholar.google.ca/scholar?start=20&q=polymer&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5
to 
https://scholar.google.ca/scholar?start=30&q=polymer&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5

ie. The start=30 then 40 etc.

Then you can loop over the author names base on the link path in the gs_a class tags.

Let me know if this helps!

-Kyle

Comment: I am interested in the total number of citations of each author, not the papers

Answer (score 0):

To get all the profiles for any "category" (label:query), or a "name" you could use a third party solution like SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free trial.

Example python code (available in other libraries also):

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "api_key": "SECRET_API_KEY",
  "engine": "google_scholar_profiles",
  "q": "Coffee",
  "hl": "en",
  "mauthors": "label:anaphylaxis"
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()
```

Example JSON output:

```json
"profiles": [
  {
    "name": "Jerrold H Levy",
    "link": "https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&user=qnH5V28AAAAJ",
    "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?author_id=qnH5V28AAAAJ&engine=google_scholar_author&hl=en",
    "author_id": "qnH5V28AAAAJ",
    "affiliations": "Professor of Anesthesiology and Surgery (Cardiothoracic)",
    "email": "Verified email at duke.edu",
    "cited_by": 80353,
    "interests": [
      {
        "title": "bleeding",
        "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_scholar_profiles&hl=en&mauthors=label%3Ableeding",
        "link": "https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&view_op=search_authors&mauthors=label:bleeding"
      },
      {
        "title": "anaphylaxis",
        "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_scholar_profiles&hl=en&mauthors=label%3Aanaphylaxis",
        "link": "https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&view_op=search_authors&mauthors=label:anaphylaxis"
      },
      {
        "title": "anticoagulation",
        "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_scholar_profiles&hl=en&mauthors=label%3Aanticoagulation",
        "link": "https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&view_op=search_authors&mauthors=label:anticoagulation"
      },
      {
        "title": "shock",
        "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_scholar_profiles&hl=en&mauthors=label%3Ashock",
        "link": "https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&view_op=search_authors&mauthors=label:shock"
      }
    ],
    "thumbnail": "https://scholar.googleusercontent.com/citations?view_op=small_photo&user=qnH5V28AAAAJ&citpid=2"
  },
  ...
}
```

You can check out the [documentation](https://serpapi.com/google-scholar-profiles-api) for more details.

Disclaimer: I work at SerpApi.